# TinyMCE and Image Cropping

Tags: image-processing, tinymce

I am writing a plugin for TinyMCE to crop images. This code works on firefox but doesn’t seem to work in other browsers.

Basically, I’m using JCrop to get the co-ordinates of the image and selected area and passing it to a server-side
method which does the cropping and returns the updated width, height and image src.

After, getting back the results. I update the image dimensions and src as follows.

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().src  = croppedImageSource;
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().width =  croppedImageWidth;
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().height = croppedImageHeight;
```

The Server-side method and crop co-ordinates are working as expected. While, the above code is not working well. Works on firefox but not on other browsers.

I was wondering If was updating the image selected in TinyMCE correctly?

Here is my full javascript function

```
function cropAndSave()
{
    var imgSrc = document.getElementById('jcrop_target').src;

    if(checkJcropCoords())
    {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "/DocViewImageCrop.page",
            type: 'POST',
            data:
            {
                imgData:    imgSrc,
                cW:         $("#w").val(),
                cH:         $("#h").val(),
                cX:         $("#x").val(),
                cY:         $("#y").val()
            },
            dataType:  'json',
            complete: function(xmlRequestObject, successString)
            {
                var fileExists = xmlRequestObject.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("fileExists")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                if(fileExists == undefined || fileExists == "false")
                {
                    alert('Image not found on server. Try uploading the image, before attempting to resize');
                }
                else
                {
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().src =    xmlRequestObject.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("imgsrc")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().width =  xmlRequestObject.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("width")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().height = xmlRequestObject.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("height")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().setAttribute('scr', croppedImageSource);
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().setAttribute('width',  croppedImageWidth);
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().setAttribute('height', croppedImageHeight);
```

or jQuery

```
var $node = $( tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode() );
$node.attr('scr', croppedImageSource);
$node.attr('width',  croppedImageWidth);
$node.attr('height', croppedImageHeight);
```